# Validate file exist in the AjaxFileUpload are uploaded or Pending

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can I validate that the file selected in AjaxFileUpload is already uploaded or are Pending

[image]

Here is my .aspx page code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
        Width="400px" OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete" Mode="Auto" />       
</form>
```

.aspx.cs code is

```
 protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName));
    }
```

I had implement java script as through which I am able to validate that file exist in Ajaxfileupload or not but which file is Pending for that I am not able to validate.

```
  function validate() {
        if ($(".ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo").length > 0) {
            alert('file exist .');
        }
        else {
            alert('select your file');
        }
    }
```

Suppose I had already uploaded 2 files and then after I add a new file to get upload but How can I validate that 2 files are uploaded and the new placed file is not uploaded.
I need to validate this from java script

**I need to validate this on any button onclientclick event.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found the answer that worked for me 
Implement the code

```
function validateImageUploaded() {
    if ($(".ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo").length > 0) {
        if ($("div.ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo").children('div').hasClass("pendingState"))
        {
            alert("found");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('select your file');
        return false;
    }
}
```